# Is it possible to use a Button outside datagrid to control data display in Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to Stack Overflow. I want to ask if it is possible to use a button outside datagrid to control data display in Datagrid in WPF C#?

I read something, but most of them are putting a button in one column in datagrid. Can anyone give some information?

Comment: Can you give some extra info, for example some code examples of what you want to do, but doesn't work?

Comment: "Stock Overflow" — really? 

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "data display in DataGrid"? I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I have a datagrid. I can display data in the datagrid. One or two column is calculated by using other columns. I can binding this column to a converter to display, but when use converter, it can only display data, not  the typed in data. So I want to use a button outside the datagrid, when I click it, the data in datagrid can updated. I tried, the data is calculated, but can't display in datagrid.

Comment: can you please explain your goal of using this button and modifications will take place in data grid?

Comment: I want to put all the calculation in the button. When Click the button, the data will be calculated, and then updated in the datagrid.

Comment: are you using MVVM?

Comment: If there is a button outside the datagrid, even if the column is binding to a variable, but after click the button, the the column is not updated.

Comment: Yeah, I am using MVVM.

Comment: are you using observable collection and binding is two way?

Answer (score 0):

Bind (two way) your data grid to an observable collection of object. On-Button-click, update the property of objects (as you want) which are being displayed in datagrid.

Comment: using observable collection and observable Object are the same, right?

Comment: no yet, working on it. and i am trying to do the button in ViewModel instead of in the View.